# Android - can't start activity of a library project

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I am developing a library. I want that an application using my library should be able to start my main activity via implicit intents using my custom action. But custom intent is not working. It says "no activity found to handle intent with action = 'my custom action'". Below is my code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("my.custom.action");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
intent.putExtra("foo","bar");
startActivity(intent);
```

I have also tried using the package name to get intent but it didn't work either (though I don't want to use this method since I don't want to expose my package name and components)

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.happay.android.acslibrary");
```

Finally I tried using explicit intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,LibMainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

This didn't throw exception but didn't open my library activity. It just opened the same activity from my main project.
Here is my Library project manifest where I register my activity :

```
<activity android:name=".LibMainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="my.custom.action" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the category from the `Intent` you pass to `startActivity()`. You added category `LAUNCHER` to the `Intent`, but your `<intent-filter>` only contains  category `DEFAULT`. There is no match. According to the [documentation for matching `Intent`s](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html):

> Categories match if all of the categories in the Intent match
>   categories given in the filter. Extra categories in the filter that
>   are not in the Intent will not cause the match to fail. Note that
>   unlike the action, an IntentFilter with no categories will only match
>   an Intent that does not have any categories.

Comment: this was a mistake while posting question. In code I am using same category. I have edited question.

Comment: Also in documentation it's written if no category is used while registering, no category should be used in intent. But with no category app crashes. With same category same calling activity is started again.